# Querying Reagent/Hiccup Markup For Tests

Tags: testing, clojure, clojurescript, hiccup

I want to test a Reagent/Re-Frame view by asserting properties of the Hiccup markup it returns. Therefore I need functions that traverse the tree, filter it, or check that certain elements with certain attributes are present.

I can not be the first to have this problem, yet Google wasn't very helpful. Is there a library that does that? If not, how would you, e.g., write a function that traverses the markup and returns a seq of all elements with a certain tag?

Comment: Please specify your actual problem and the code, that failed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can analyze and modify any tree-like data structure using the [Tupelo Forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc).  Please view the [Lightning Talk video](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM) and peruse [the many live examples](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj).

If you add more detail to your question I can update the answer with something specific.

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338077/how-to-find-the-path-of-keys-to-a-value-in-a-nested-array-map-in-clojure/61355001#61355001).

Comment: It seems to me that `tupelo.forest` isn't available in ClojureScript, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, yes, it is CLJ only at present.  I am working on an upgrade that will support CLJS also. You could use the `walk-with-parents-readonly` as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at:

- Convert the hiccup out to HTML then use HTML selectors to do analysis
- Put the tree inside DataScript then use datalog to do analysis

  - More details here https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/datascript-dom.html
- Explore the sea of libraries for data filtering:

  - https://github.com/noprompt/meander
  - https://github.com/BrunoBonacci/where

There's a lot of ways of doing this it's hard to suggest a good answer